# Python 3 - Getting some strings from a HTTPrequest response

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, httprequest, text-parsing

I'm having a hard time extracting data from a httprequest response.

Can somebody help me? Here's a part of my code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.example.com', verify=True)
keyword = r.text.find('loginfield')
print (keyword)

>>> 42136
```

**42136** value basically means that string '*loginfield*' exists on the response.text. But how do I extract specific strings from it?

Like for example I want to extract these exact strings:

```
<title>Some title here</title>
```

or this one:

```
<div id='bla...' #continues extracting of strings until it stops where I want it to stop extracting.
```

Anybody got an idea on how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse HTML and get tags. Here's an example piece of code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com', verify=True)
soup = BS(r.text)
print(soup.find('title').text)
```

Should print:

```
Some title here
```

But depends on if it's the first title or not

Comment: Thanks!! But I heard BS doesn't work well in Python 3.x, and what if I want to extract multiple divs like the third block of codes I wrote in the OP?

Comment: @ArthurCodova You can then use `find_all`, which, surprise surprise!, gets all the titles. THen you can get the third element (`[2]`) and call `.text`. As far as if it doesn't go well in python 3, I'm not exactly sure, because I mainly use python 2.7. But I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I couldn't find the module bs4? How can I get this. Kinda new to python

Comment: @Micah Check out https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for HTML-page data extraction, you should take a look at a specialized library like [Beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Your program will be less fragile and more maintainable that way.

---

[`string.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) will return **-1** if the string does *not* exists.

There is no string "loginfield" in the page you retrieved.

---

Once you have the correct index for your string, the returned value is the position of the first char of that string.

since you edited your question:

```
>>> r.text.find('loginfield') 
42136
```

That means, the string "loginfield" starts at offset 42136 in the text. You could display say 200 chars starting at that position that way:

```
>>> print(r.text[42136:42136+200])
```

To find the various values you looking for, you have to figure out where there are relative to that position.

Comment: oh shit!! thanks for the correction, it is because I always put

if keyword != -1:
print ('found keyword')

Maybe that's why I'm confused. But still, no answer for my question :|